# Android drawable oval shape with center out of bound

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I'm willing to declare a xml drawable with semi-circle. So the center of the oval is out of the bound:
[image: what i want]

I tried doing it with scale tag but i can't get it to work, here is what i have done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <scale android:scaleGravity="center">
            <shape android:shape="ring">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#C8C8D7"/>
                <size
                    android:width="300dp"
                    android:height="300dp"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it have to be a drawable? You can draw an arc on a canvas

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to generate it inside xml. I ended up using canvas drawing.

```
public Drawable generateHeaderBackground(int arcColor) {
    int w = screenWidth;
    x = (int) r.getDimension(R.dimen.header_height);
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, x, conf);
    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(bmp);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setColor(arcColor);
    p.setStrokeWidth(3);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);

    RectF rtt = new RectF(-w / 2, x / 4, w + (w / 2), x * 8);
    mCanvas.drawOval(rtt, p);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
}
```